# How to loop through fields in a subclass using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I need to loop through the public properties in a subclass of an abstract base class. I have used reflection for this sort of thing before, but now I need to also retrieve the fields that are in the super class. The following method returns only those fields in a subclass, but not the super class. how would one access members of the base class as well?

```
private <T> void inspectClass(Class<T> cls){
    Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    Log.d("FIELDS ARRAY", cls.toString());
    for(Field f : fields){
        Log.d("FIELD NAME", f.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `while(Class#getSuperClass() != null)` to loop through parent classes and get their fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [getFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) method that will return all **public** fields of this class and its superclass.

If you want all fields of this class and its superclass, just use [getSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29)() and call the same method.

As the comment by @Sotirios suggests, you can keep doing this all the way up the hierarchy.

```
Class<?> clazz = cls.getSuperclass();
    while (clazz != null) {
        // Print fields.
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get all the public fields of the class you should use `getFields`. The java documentation says:

```
 Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the accessible public
 fields of the class or interface represented by this Class object.
```

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for the documentation of `java.lang.Class`.